# Converting Alarm Activity App into Service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have one app that uses AlarmManager to play a specific song after every hour. The problem with this is, my app doesn't run in background for a long. I observe it gets killed after an hour or so. As a result the app doesn't play the song the whole day. I want my app to run all the times and trigger AlarmManager to play a song.
Can anyone help how can I convert my app into service so that it could run all the times, all the days?

Below are the code snippets I have.

MainAcitivity.java-- This is the main activity. Its purpose is to show a UI where users can choose the hours when they want song to be played:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
....
Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("Hey ! My first alarm event !");
mainActivityGlobalInstance=this;
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shanti);
final int POLLING_SECONDS=1;
final Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
final PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
final Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startAlarm);
final Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), POLLING_SECONDS*1000, pi);
start.setEnabled(false);
stop.setEnabled(true);
stop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){
am.cancel(pi);
stop.setEnabled(false);
start.setEnabled(true);
}
});
start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), POLLING_SECONDS*1000, pi);
stop.setEnabled(true);
start.setEnabled(false);
}
});
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings){
setFlags();
Intent intent=new Intent(this,chooseHours.class);
startActivity(intent);
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In above main activity I have the instance created for MediaPlayer and AlarmManager

AlarmReceiver.java-- This extends BroadcastReceiver and onReceive plays a song if Mediaplayer is already not running:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
try{
if(intent != null && MainActivity.mp != null && MainActivity.mainActivityGlobalInstance != null){
if(intent.getAction().equals("Hey ! My first alarm event !")){
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
if(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0){
if( //conditions here
){
if(!MainActivity.mp.isPlaying())
MainActivity.mp.start();
}
}
}
}
}catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Error Occured: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}

}
```

chooseHours.java -- This is an activity that presents a UI to choose hours

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can recall your AlarmReceiver Broadcast again after some time from the Broadcast class using Intent. Just like Recursive method.

Comment: No brother. U can see i have media player reference from mainactivity. If mainactivity is killed after some time, nothing will work

Comment: Friends, any suggestions/comments ??

Comment: @ravitiwari Hi...Create a music service class. Make the media player instance there. In the OnStartCommand method start the player instance.